# Suppress rendering of html from template-literals within another template-literal

Tags: javascript, html, css, template-literals

I'd like to display some html code that is within a template literals within another template literal.

I am using `<pre><code>` tags to attempt this.

The problem I'm having at the moment is that the browser renders the html rather than its code. For example it displays an actual input box in place of displaying the code, e.g. `<input ...`

I'd like to apply some reversible process using javascript to the `templateliteral` variable so that the html is displayed literally (it should display all orange on black text in the below snippet), and so that the original code can be easily got back.

What might be a good way to do this?

Here is an example of the problem (it should display all orange on black text):

```js
let templateliteral = `let inner = { content : \`
<style>
#exampleDivInTemplateLiteral { background-color:lightblue;color:white; }
</style>

<div id="exampleDivInTemplateLiteral">
    <b>this is some text.</b>
    <input id="exampleInput" placeholder="example input">\</input>
</div>\`}`


document.getElementById("exampleDiv").innerHTML = '<pre><code>' + templateliteral + '<pre></code>'
```

```html
<div id="exampleDiv" style="background-color:black;color:orange;">

<div>
```

**Note this is specific to template literals within template literals.**

***Posting in edited form so I can post answer***

Answer (score 0):

I used `createElement` and `innerText` (in place of `innerHTML`):

```js
let templateliteral = `let inner = { content : \`
<style>
#exampleDivInTemplateLiteral { background-color:lightblue;color:white; }
</style>

<div id="exampleDivInTemplateLiteral">
    <b>this is some text.</b>
    <input id="exampleInput" placeholder="example input">\</input>
</div>\`}`

let divel = document.getElementById("exampleDiv")
let preel = document.createElement("pre");
let codeel = document.createElement("code");
preel.appendChild(codeel)
divel.appendChild(preel)
codeel.innerText =  templateliteral
```

```html
<div id="exampleDiv" style="background-color:black;color:orange;">

<div>
```